# Is there a phrase for making someone do something that is your duty by making it look like it is their responsibility?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In Hindi there is phrase for this which literally translates to "*putting something (a task) on someone's head*" and another which translates to "*sticking a task on someone*".

Comment: _foist_, _devolve_, if words will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the idiom/phrase you can use when someone tells you to do (the work) that he is assigned to do (in reality it is assigned to him)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468405/what-is-the-idiom-phrase-you-can-use-when-someone-tells-you-to-do-the-work-tha) ('unload it on someone else', 'pass the buck')

Answer (score 1):

I think to **pass the buck** is similar. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/buck) defines it as

> Shift the responsibility for something to someone else.

For the meaning of **buck**, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=buck) quotes an 1887 book on poker:

> The 'buck' is any inanimate object, usually [a] knife or pencil, which
> is thrown into a jack pot and temporarily taken by the winner of the
> pot. Whenever the deal reaches the holder of the 'buck', a new jack
> pot must be made."

Comment: Dammit, slipped my mind. +1 :)

Comment: @user405662: :-) I've got a feeling there's *another* expression out there though, and that one's slipped **my** mind.